# VisualStudioCodeCredential: The refresh token has expired due to inactivity

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I keep getting the error:

> VisualStudioCodeCredential: Azure Active Directory error '(invalid_grant) AADSTS700082: The refresh token has expired due to inactivity.

So I signed out and signed in again using `Azure Account` extension but still got the same error. Anyone knows why? Or where can I delete the cached credential for vscode?

Vscode Version: 1.69.2
Azure Account version: 0.11.0

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's likely a problem with the version of the Azure Account extension for VSCode.

Here they suggest to downgrade it to 0.9.11 or earlier: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/23584#issuecomment-1075332922

I did solve the problem with the downgrade (and after logging out from Azure Account).

Comment: This answer cannot be upvoted enough.  We ran into major issues authenticating with Azure Keyvault due to the broken token refresh functionality in the VSCode extension.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `~/.azuredatastudio/argv.json` file from my local solved it for me. However this would remove all connections.